# supertabular: how to change font size and add caption?

Tags: supertabular

1) How to use small or tiny fonts in supertabular ?

2) How to embed captions in supertabular?

I tried some possible options but they are not working.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\begin{document}
\begin{supertabular}{ll}
    \hline
    AA & BB\\
    CC & DD\\
    \hline
\end{supertabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For "embed captions in supertabular" do you intend to have a caption on everypage or only at the beginning of the supertabular? Moreover, please complete your code snippet to make it compilable.

Comment: I want caption only at the end of supertable. I have completed the code snippet.

Answer (score 3):

`supertabular` provides a caption mechanism that is quite different from the standard captions. The following three commands are provided: `\tablecaption`, `\topcaption` and `\bottomcaption` that position the caption accordingly.

To position the caption only on the last page under the table, use `\bottomcaption` as shown in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\begin{document}
\bottomcaption{some caption}
\begin{supertabular}{ll}
    \hline
    AA & BB\\
    CC & DD\\
    \hline 
\end{supertabular}
\end{document}
```

Changing the font size in a `supertabular` could be done as follows. In this case, `\small` affects all the whole table, while `\tiny` only affects the following cell.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\begin{document}
\bottomcaption{some caption}\small
\begin{supertabular}{ll}
    \hline
    AA & BB\\
    \tiny CC & DD\\
    \hline 
\end{supertabular}
\end{document}
```